# How can I get the correct output with Moment.js and "fromNow"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

For the below program, the run date is `26/10/2017` and the variable `deadline=29/10/2017`.

I am using moment.js:

```js
var deadline = '29/10/2017'
var days = moment(deadline, "DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow();
console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

My output is `in 2 days` but actually I think the right answer is `in 3 days`

I think it is because `fromNow`is also calulating with the hours, so my question is, how can I reset this, so that I get the correct output?

Comment: I'm presuming 'now' includes the time whereas the deadline is from `00:00`, hence it's two full days. This is just an assumption without seeing any useful snippets of your code though. Could you update your question to provide more detail

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated it. The interesting thing is. With higher days like `4 days` or `5 days` this is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.endOf('day')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) on your deadline momentjs instance and you'll get 3 days.

You can also use a timestamp on top of your date such as `23:59` to get the same functionality.

```js
var deadline = '29/10/2017'
var days = moment(deadline, "DD/MM/YYYY").endOf('day').fromNow();
// Change the time to 23:59:59           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `fromNow` you can use `from`. With this, you can reset today's date to midnight and compare it against that instead:

```js
var deadline = '29/10/2017',
    now = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0),
    days = moment(deadline, "DD/MM/YYYY").from(now);

console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```